# adding a field to opencart product form

Tags: php, opencart, shopping-cart, opencart2.x

i would like to add an input field to opencart product form. the field should passed to the server and save like other fields. i added the field to the product form tpl file and passed it to the checkout/cart controller class and the 'add' method with:

```
data: $('#product input[type=\'text\'], #product input[type=\'hidden\'], #product input[type=\'radio\']:checked, #product input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, #product select, #product textarea , #choosed_color'),
```

in the $('#button-cart').on('click' event.

i can access the field value in the 'add' method with:

```
$this->request->post['choosed_color']
```

how can i show it in the shopping cart and pre-factor?
thanks...

Comment: Did you try adding it as option in product?

Comment: no. it is a special function and i can't Implement that as an option. if it is'nt an option, can i save it like an option?

Comment: Nope then you can't. But you can save it is an individual field. Like sku, ukc etc etc

Comment: Do you know about custom field option? You can define your own custom field in opencart for products.

Comment: i didn't know how can i define a custom field. so i defined a text option field and initialized that with the user selected(or entered) value before send data to saving in the cart. just i should do an extra operation in this solution. i should define a text option for any product that i would to use the custom option in it. because in this solution i can't use any text input options anymore, i defined the mentioned input field with a specific name and before initialize that with the user selected value i checked if any option with that specific name exists the initializing done..

Comment: this solution worked correctly. but i know this is complex and difficult and illogical way. before that i didn't know how can i define a custom field in opencart. but now i believe that define a custom field certainly is a better and simplest solution. thanks...

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own custom field in opencart for products. That is the precise and correct way of doing it. Or if you are a programmer, you can alter the code as well.